# Why can't I input this variable into the modulo command?

Tags: python, string, modulo

I'm extremely new to this but I still don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
    print("Multiple Finder 2.0.1")
    print("MF2.0.1 will find the multiples of any number between point A and point B")
    multiple = input("Find the multiples of what number: ")
    startPoint = input("Enter Point A: ")
    endPoint = input("Enter Point B: ")
    x = startPoint
    while x <= endPoint:
    if x % str(multiple) == 0:
    print(x)
    x = x + 1
```

and I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/---", line 8, in <module>
    if x % str(multiple) == 0:
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: What do you expect `12 % 'foo'` to be?

Comment: @Blender -- I'm guessing OP is using python3.x in which case it would be more like `'12' % 'foo'` (which also reproduces the traceback) ...

Comment: @mgilson: Ah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well, % can do two things in python. For numbers, its the modulo operation. For strings, its the format operation. Since both x and str(...) are strings, python is trying to do the latter ad then compare it to a number. I think what you want is:

```
multiple = input("Find the multiples of what number: ")
startPoint = int(input("Enter Point A: ")) #use int() to get numbers from strings
endPoint = int(input("Enter Point B: ")) 
x = startPoint
while x <= endPoint:
    if x % multiple == 0: #modulo two integers
        print(x)
    x = x + 1
```